# How can i get rid of annoying autoformatting in my VS code?

Tags: reactjs, indentation, autoformat

I uninstalled prettier and my Format On Save is unchecked but i don't know why my codes is still auto formatted. Anybody can help me? Thank you so much!
This is how it looks like:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Btw, this is my setting.json:

```
{
    "java.debug.settings.stepping.skipStaticInitializers": true,
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
    "html.format.enable": false,
    "html.format.preserveNewLines": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceBeforeAndAfterBinaryOperators": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingEmptyBraces": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterKeywordsInControlFlowStatements": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingNonemptyBraces": false,
    "typescript.format.enable": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterCommaDelimiter": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterSemicolonInForStatements": false,
    "javascript.format.enable": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking at your global settings.
Check inside `.vscode/settings.json` to see if there is anything that sets autoformat on save to True. If there is, just delete that line altogether, it will default to your default setting.

Comment: yah i have just added my setting.json in my question, hopefully you can see it!

Comment: everything is set to false tho in my setting.json

Comment: Could you send your setting json files.
Just so we can inspect.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's not your formatter, but rather your linter. Ideally, you'd add your own lint config file so you can manage it yourself in your project.
Do you have eslint installed?

You can hover your mouse over any of the red lines and you should get a tooltip with how to fix the problem. Can you send a screenshot of that?

Comment: i'm not sure if this is what you mean by estlin, it's in my package.json: ""eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]"

Comment: Yea, you can either disable the eslint or configure your formatter to work with this eslint config to fix your errors for you.

Comment: I use prettier for formatting and eslint for linting so I use the eslint-prettier plugin to aid in getting these playing nice.  You may consider giving that a shot.  For now, you can update your eslint config to simply warn you, not throw an error.
If you are using prettier, take a look here.
https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html

Comment: I only use Vue which is probably slightly different here, but I did find this article for configuring for react.
https://medium.com/how-to-react/config-eslint-and-prettier-in-visual-studio-code-for-react-js-development-97bb2236b31a

Answer (score 0):

It may have been happened by wrong language mode in vscode. and this can be fixed by changing the language mode of the editor in VSCode. todo this, go to the **bottom-right** corner in vscode and click on **name of a programming language or file type**. after that a searching space will pop up. then enter the language mode you want to be in. hopefully that will help!

Peace!!

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstalling eslint vscode extension plugin solved my issue.